# Failed to Get SDP Description : 404 Stream not found testRTSPClient in LIVE555

Tags: testing, rtsp, live555

I am new to Live555 and have recently started to learn a few things about it. The docs state that a good test would be to try out the samples given in testProgs folder that is in the source code. So, I have started to test a few programs which are readily available in the live555 source.

From the mediaServer folder I am running the server as per docs I should place the movie file (mp4) in the same place as the exe. Which I did. When I try to open the client (testRTSPClient.exe),
I keep getting the error for SDP description as shown in the screen shot.

What am I doing wrong? Does it mean I provide a SDP files at the client end? Could not find such a statement in their docs which are pretty obscure at the moment.

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

live555MediaServer doesn't support mp4 file.

When you start it, it prints something like:

```
LIVE555 Media Server
    version 0.84 (LIVE555 Streaming Media library version 2014.09.11).
Play streams from this server using the URL
    rtsp://192.168.0.16:8554/<filename>
where <filename> is a file present in the current directory.
Each file's type is inferred from its name suffix:
    ".264" => a H.264 Video Elementary Stream file
    ".265" => a H.265 Video Elementary Stream file
    ".aac" => an AAC Audio (ADTS format) file
    ".ac3" => an AC-3 Audio file
    ".amr" => an AMR Audio file
    ".dv" => a DV Video file
    ".m4e" => a MPEG-4 Video Elementary Stream file
    ".mkv" => a Matroska audio+video+(optional)subtitles file
    ".mp3" => a MPEG-1 or 2 Audio file
    ".mpg" => a MPEG-1 or 2 Program Stream (audio+video) file
    ".ogg" or ".ogv" or ".opus" => an Ogg audio and/or video file
    ".ts" => a MPEG Transport Stream file
        (a ".tsx" index file - if present - provides server 'trick play' support)
    ".vob" => a VOB (MPEG-2 video with AC-3 audio) file
    ".wav" => a WAV Audio file
    ".webm" => a WebM audio(Vorbis)+video(VP8) file
See http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/ for additional documentation.
(We use port 8000 for optional RTSP-over-HTTP tunneling, or for HTTP live streaming (for indexed Transport Stream files only).)
```

You should use one of the supported formats, for instance `mkv`.